# When we use each function in jquery,we should add return false,It is right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkboxall and checkbox group.When I click the checkboxall, all the  checkbox group will be checked.When I make all the  checkbox group checked,the checkboxall will be checked.I write the codes like these,but my parner say that add   `return false` will be better.It is right?I find that add `return true` or `return` is also  well.How about `break`?

```
 $("#CheckedAll").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){   
             $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').attr("checked", true );
        }else{                              
             $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').attr("checked", false );
        }
 });
 $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').click(function(){
           var flag=true;
           $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').each(function(){
                if(!this.checked){
                     flag = false;
                           return false; //return;return true,break;?
                }
           });
           if( flag ){
                 $('#CheckedAll').attr('checked', true );
           }else{
                 $('#CheckedAll').attr('checked', false );
           }
 });
```

Comment: Note that you will have issues with this code, and that you should change `attr()` to `prop()`, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/aJ529/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague is right: once you find one instance of a checked checkbox, there's no point in continuing the loop. `return false` stops the each loop from iterating. `break` won't do anything because `.each()` is not a native loop and returning something other than false will stop the current iteration but not the entire loop.

That said, you can avoid the each loop entirely and simplify the code considerably. Also, you need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. Try this:

```
$("#CheckedAll").click(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});

$('input[type=checkbox][name=items]').click(function () {
    $('#CheckedAll').prop(
        'checked',
        $('input[type=checkbox][name=items]:not(:checked)').length === 0
    );
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmYp5/)

Answer (score 4):

When you're using jQuery `each`  - you want to return `false` *only* when you want to stop the loop.

Neither return / return true would stop the loop from iterating.

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5];

$.each(a,function (i,n){
  if (n==2) return;
  console.log(n)

})
```

result = 1,3,4,5

```
 $.each(a,function (i,n){
      if (n==2) return true;
      console.log(n)

    })
```

result = 1,3,4,5

```
 $.each(a,function (i,n){
      if (n==2) return false;
      console.log(n)

    })
```

result = 1

```
$.each(a,function (i,n){
  if (n==2) break;
  console.log(n)

})
```

result  : Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Answer (score 2):

"We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."

It depends on your intentions. If you need to stop looping, return false. Otherwise, you do not need to return anything given your provided code.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't allow "**break**" keyword like in many other programming languages.
neither **returning true** will sneak you out of the loop.

so to get the behavior of **break** statement with jQuery, **better you return false.** 
for the equivalent output.

Comment: Techincally jQuery is not a programming language.